# Findnig the k-th Maximum of a set of real numbers algebraically

Tags: number-theory

I am interested in learning more about Theorem 1-4 in the following link:
[Optimization in integers and related extremal problems](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=gLPhBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&dq=%22kth%20largest%20number%22%20-quicksort&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBWoVChMI7bXk6ZjZyAIVy7YaCh2ahgPZ#v=onepage&q=%22kth%20largest%20number%22%20-quicksort&f=false)

**Edit 2:** 
Same information is [here.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uiMzR79XLKmE0_h05idGFaqovmkKyWyWervy1cn3yqY/pub), if you still can't get to it, see Google books with the following information:

In case your browser is blocking the link for some reason, the information is on the book "Optimization In Integers and Related Extermal Problems" by Thomas L. Saaty - Theorem 1.4.

My questions:

1. Does the theorem work for negative, positive and repeated numbers?
2. Is M (lower bound=1, upper bound=x) = Max. number of the x numbers where x>=1?
3. I would like to see some worked examples on the web. Any references would be appreciated.
4. Which Math subject studies this theorem and/or which books give more details about it.
5. Does this theorem have a name?

Any help would be appreciated. Thx.

**EDIT:** This is not a homework or job related question. It is for personal interest only.

Comment: Google is not letting me see that page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks other people to do all the work

Comment: @Yemon Choi, I have a personal interst in this theorem and I am not a student or a worker in any related field, so this is not a work asked from me. I want help and this site, to the best of my understanding is for such. I have tried to research this subject personally but could not find any answers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank for taking the time to look into this one. I edited the text to show the book title and theorem number. I could attempt to type the text in if you so desire. The link is correct and is working of FireFox browser. Maybe there is a problem with other browsers.

Comment: Google let me see the page before that one, and the page after, but not that page.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank you for your reply. I included the relevant part here - Hope this works: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uiMzR79XLKmE0_h05idGFaqovmkKyWyWervy1cn3yqY/pub

Comment: @YemonChoi, well I would like the moderator to move the question since I can't cross post.